# How to create a diagram for my data

Tags: microsoft-excel, diagrams

I am doing the Google HashCode practice and I would like to visualize some data. I thought of using Excel for this. Example data:

Earliest start:     186, 208, 228, 244, 281
Distance of ride:   479, 969, 482, 1011, 372

Time steps are from 1 to 25'000 in general (in the sample data you see only the beginning).

I explain the data that I want to visualize:
The first column has earliest start time at step 186 and a distance of 479. A time step and unit of distance are equivalent in this case.

So the ride starts at time 186 and lasts for 479 steps. Finish would be at time/step 665.

So I thought of visualizing each ride (ride number 1,2,3,4,5,....) on the y-axis and each start and distance as a line along the x-axis.

I have no idea how to do that in Excel. I tried to fiddle around but I fail to understand how to choose the data range appropriately unfortunately.

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Start with selecting all your data then go to `Insert -> chart`, explore and play around with the different chart types and get back to us if/when you have more questions

Comment: Also, graphs typically plot a *dependent* variable on the y-axis vs an *independent* variable on the x-axis.  Excel assumes the independent variable is the first column of the data.  So the structure of your data table will affect how the graph looks.  You probably want ride number on the x-axis.  You could create a column graph where the height of the bars would represent start time and distance.  And there are many other possibilities.  Try various graphs and check in  back here as @cyber suggested.

Comment: Note: Excel's "bar" graph has horizontal bars rather than vertical bars as in the "column" graph.  For that graph, the y-axis is the independent variable.

Comment: I think you want a stacked bar chart to visualize the way I think you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the type of chart you are looking for, it is quite easy in Excel.

- Use 3 columns: Ride #, Start, Distance.
- select all the data
- On the Insert menu in Excel, click on the Bar Chart icon and choose the "2-D Stacked Bar".
- You should get a chart that looks a lot like this, but we still need to hide the first part of the bar. So, right-click on chart and choose "Format Chart Area..."
- Click on "Plot Area Options" and choose Series 1
- Set Fill to No Fill and Border to No Line

[image]

Comment: That's a very nice graph, but his "start" data are **times**.

Comment: Actually that is perfectly what I needed. I was not clear in my question maybe, but a time unit and a distance can be considered to be equivalent. This is exactly what I trie to do. Thank you Mr. Godfrey.